# Get product attribute measurement in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

How to get the width of Product UoM in magento2

Ex: Weight : 100 cm

[image: measurement]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product->getTsDimensionsLength();
$product->getTsDimensionsWidth();
$product->getTsDimensionsHeight();
```

or use this

```
$height = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_dimensions_height'); 
$Value = $height->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$width = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_dimensions_width'); 
$Value = $width->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$length = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_dimensions_length'); 
$Value = $length->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: I want to get the unit of width ?

Comment: check updated code.

Comment: Its give only value not unit of length(cm) ...

Comment: shortest way you can do it manually like 
$width = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_dimensions_width'); 
$Value = $width->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) .'cm';

Comment: Is it a proper way ?

Comment: yes, because may magento can not store value with cm or inch it's store only value.

Comment: Similarly ...how to get  unit of measurement of weight?

Comment: same dude just concat lbs,kg,etc with weight value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these values like below code

```
<?php if($product->getWidth()): ?>
    <b>Width:</b><?php echo $product->getWidth(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or if you want to display these values in More Information tab then just update these attributes by go to **Stores -> Attributes -> Product from left side menu.**

Click on Attribute you want to display inside details page.

Now click on **Storefront Properties** tab from left sidebar, **Set Yes on Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront.**

and Save Atribute and Clear cache

Comment: but i need to display "Width : 150 cm" ... how to get the unit of length(cm)